# Eclipse: Compile AspectJ class with Java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, aspectj, ajdt

How would I compile `.aj` class in my Eclipse Web Project? I already have `AspectJ Development Tools` installed in `Eclipse Juno`. But it didn't make any difference. Using Tomcat 6 server to deploy application.

```
Note: I have some groovy classes too which I have compiled using Groovy-Eclipse plugin.
```

I am not using Maven or any other build tool in my application. Just want to run it on localhost to test few things. I really don't to spend time installing and configuring Maven for application.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, a groovy project cannot also use the AspectJ compiler.  So, you must separate out all your aspects from your groovy project.  If you need to weave into your groovy code, you will need to place your groovy project on the in path of your aspectj project.  This will weave the already compiled groovy code and place it in an output folder of the aspectj project.